# What is the best alternative to Java's Optional if it isn't supported by earlier Android API versions?

Tags: java, android

When I attempt to use `Optional.empty()`, my IDE warns me that `Call requires API level 24 (current min is 21): java.util.Optional#empty`.

I'm assuming I cannot use Optional. Should I use `null`? Is there a best-practice alternative?

Comment: But [there is no best practice](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164).  You should stop asking for "best practice" advice.  And tell your friends / teachers / colleagues to stop telling you that XYZ is "best practice".

Comment: API 21 is Lollipop 5.0.  That was released in 2015.  Maybe it is time to not support it anymore.  See also https://endoflife.date/android.  You shouldn't be encouraging users to continue using a platform that is EOL.  It is bad for >their< security.

Comment: @StephenC While that may be true, the percentage of Android phones with a version older than 7.0 (which I believe introduced Java 8 & Optionals) is around~6%, which is significant percentage that you still want to reach.

Comment: Yea ... no.  You have 94% of your market.  Don't be **greedy**.  It is not in your customer's interests to be encouraging them to use a woefully out-dated and (probably) insecure phone.  Ethics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use Java's Optional, even with an older min SDK level. The key is to add this to your 'build.gradle':

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Use version 1.1.5 if you have Gradle older than 7.3.0
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
}
```

This will instruct Gradle to compile your Java 8 code using Optionals, even lambdas and more to Java 7 bytecode using some tricks. Note that you need Gradle version 4.0.0 or later for those to work. You can find more information on what other features you can use by doing this on the official [Android Developer website](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support), but most notable are:

- lambdas
- Streams
- newer collections

Comment: Thanks, but I checked and my build.gradle already contains these lines.

Comment: My bad, I put the wrong build.gradle on the answer (the one that allows Lambdas but not optionals). Try the updated one instead.